# Couldn't display a second word in my database output

Tags: php

I have a strange problem here.
I'm doing a admin page to edit movie info. I have a movie for exemple called "Blood Diamonds" in my database, but on the oage it only show "Blood" without the second word "diamonds", I couldnt find whyyy.

```
require('../classes/movie_class.php');
$moviecinemas = movie::get_movie_info( $_GET['movie_id']);

foreach ($moviecinemas as $movie)
{
    $movie_id = $movie['movie_id'];
    $movie_name = $movie['movie_name'];
    $movie_category = $movie['movie_category'];
    $movie_display = $movie['movie_display'];


    echo "<input name='movieid' type='hidden' id='movieid' value=" . $movie_id . '><br/>';
    echo "Movie Name :";
    echo "<input name='moviename' type='text' id='moviename' value=" . $movie_name . '><br/>';
    echo "Movie Category :";
    echo "<input name='moviecategory' type='text' id='moviecategory' value=" . $movie_category . '><br/>';}
    ?>
```

In the class page :

```
public static function get_movie_info($movie_id)
{
    $query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT *
        FROM movie
        WHERE movie_id = {$movie_id}"
    );

    while( $movie =  mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) )
    {
        $results[] = $movie;
    }

    return $results;        


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` property in your `input` tags should have quotes surrounding the movie name. Otherwise, when there's a space, it interprets the next words as more properties of the `input`.

```
echo "<input name='moviename' type='text' id='moviename' value='" . $movie_name . "'><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML tags are not set properly, missing " in value attribute : 
replace

```
echo "<input name='moviename' type='text' id='moviename' value=" . $movie_name . '><br/>';
```

by

```
echo "<input name='moviename' type='text' id='moviename' value=" . $movie_name . '"><br/>';
```

In addition you should probably encode values so that a " in a database value will not corrupt your html code (htmlentities for instance).